# Alternative to "less good at"

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar

Is there an alternative, yet polite way of saying:

> "For those less good at English"

I know it's technically correct but it doesn't sound right to me. The context is that we are offering a service aimed at people who do not have particularly strong English language skills.

I don't want to use "worse". It comes across as blunt/insulting, and also there isn't an alternative subject that we would be directly comparing them to.

Comment: Ettiquette is beyond the sope of EL&U, but IMO, singling out less-than-fluent English speakers in this way is inherently condescending. If you're offering a simple alternative expression to a mixed audience you can say something like "...or, more simply put, ..." or just use the simpler expression. Have a look at [Interpersonal skills SE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Are you saying that you are offering a service to _those who have limited English proficiency/fluency_?

Comment: Is the service you are offering one that helps them improve their language skills? If so you could say just that: for those who need to improve their language skills. Otherwise what about "for those whose English is not so good..."? It's not insulting (My Arabic is not so good either -- but I wouldn't be insulted to be offered a service in an Arabic country that didn't assume a high level of Arabic )

Comment: One polite way to express the idea you have in mind is to replace "less good" with "less fluent." Since fluency in a language is a step up from proficiency, it isn't terribly insulting to refer to someone who is only marginally proficient as "less fluent."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say:

> *For those not [well-versed](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/well-versed) in English.*
>
> *For those not [proficient](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/proficient) in English.*

These are the most viable answers, but they seem to be a bit too advanced for your target audience.

Other, more subtle and simple options:

> *For beginners and people struggling to learn English.*
>
> *For those having difficulties in learning English.*

Answer (score 2):

In PR writing, it's best to be positive:

For those seeking to improve their English language skills or proficiency, X [does] blah blah blah.

For those seeking to strengthen their English language skills or proficiency, X [does] blah blah blah.

Negatives should be avoided unless this is an academic paper.